# Click on a button for specific row on a table

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with `20` rows and `6` columns and would like to click on an Edit User button (`td5`) for a row that has named as **Area Manager**.

I would like to know how to generate `XPath` using contains function or use for loop to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: The button appears to have an ID of `edituserareamanager`. Is this attribute unique to this node? If the UI devs are building the UI correctly, there would only be one instance of this ID on the DOM. In which case, if I'm understanding your question correctly, should make for an easy locator. If not, let us know and we can help further.

Comment: In the above, the U should be capitalized (I think Ids are case sensitive, so I wouldn't want a working solution to get undermined)

Comment: I have tried to use the id as suggested without luck. Also I found out that I don’t get to see the ID anymore on the document. Is there a way to write dynamic xpath to pick the specific user edit button.